# Align text middle to image in multiple lines

Tags: css, responsive

I have the next code here:

```html
<img class="circular-portrait-user" style='vertical-align:middle;width:25%;' src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/624/cpsprodpb/C18B/production/_87974594_32be803c-efcf-47ef-9a17-197106074016.jpg" />
<span style="vertical-align: middle" class="username no-margin-bottom">AXXX</span>
<span style="vertical-align:middle" class="secondary-text no-margin-bottom">Tsad </span>
<span style="vertical-align:middle" class="secondary-text no-margin-bottom">zxzxxz </span>
```

What I want is to have every span on his own line, more exactly to have span under span. I've tried with `<br>` or with

```
style="display:block"
```

but put my text under image.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the complete HTML code

```
<div style="float:left;width:50%">
<img class="circular-portrait-user" style='vertical-align:middle;width:25%;' src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/624/cpsprodpb/C18B/production/_87974594_32be803c-efcf-47ef-9a17-197106074016.jpg" />
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:50%">
 <span style="vertical-align: middle" class="username no-margin-bottom">AXXX</span><br/>
       <span style="vertical-align:middle" class="secondary-text no-margin-bottom">Tsad </span><br/>
       <span style="vertical-align:middle" class="secondary-text no-margin-bottom">zxzxxz </span>
</div>
```

Please adjust the width according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is wrap all spans in one .wrapper like so

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.wrapper > span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img class="circular-portrait-user" style='vertical-align:middle;width:25%;' src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/624/cpsprodpb/C18B/production/_87974594_32be803c-efcf-47ef-9a17-197106074016.jpg" />
  <div class="wrapper">
     <span class="username no-margin-bottom">AXXX</span>
     <span class="secondary-text no-margin-bottom">Tsad </span>
     <span class="secondary-text no-margin-bottom">zxzxxz </span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your spans in a container...

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6srbw75q/)

```css
.span-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.span-container span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img class="circular-portrait-user" style='vertical-align:middle;width:25%;' src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/624/cpsprodpb/C18B/production/_87974594_32be803c-efcf-47ef-9a17-197106074016.jpg" />
<div class="span-container">
  <span style="vertical-align: middle" class="username no-margin-bottom">AXXX</span>
  <span style="vertical-align:middle" class="secondary-text no-margin-bottom">Tsad </span>
  <span style="vertical-align:middle" class="secondary-text no-margin-bottom">zxzxxz </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put your 3 `spans` inside a `div` and then gave the `div` a `background-image:;`.

```css
div.circular-portrait-user {
  color:#fff;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:url(http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/624/cpsprodpb/C18B/production/_87974594_32be803c-efcf-47ef-9a17-197106074016.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align:center;
  padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="circular-portrait-user">
  <span style="vertical-align: middle" class="username no-margin-bottom">AXXX</span>
  <span style="vertical-align:middle" class="secondary-text no-margin-bottom">Tsad </span>
  <span style="vertical-align:middle" class="secondary-text no-margin-bottom">zxzxxz </span>
</div>
```